# How to add image field to main navigation menu item

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I am having a problem using MYTHEME.theme file to add image field in the menu item object. I need to be able to specify an image for each menu link/item!

---

```
function HOOK_entity_base_field_info(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  $fields = [];

  if ($entity_type->id() == 'menu_link_content')
  {
   $fields['menu-image'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('image')
   ->setLabel(t('Image shown next to menu name'))
   ->setComputed(TRUE);
  }
  return $fields;
}
```

---

I don't think that this code actually runs, I cannot see any effects!

Comment: Try Simple Menu Icons it showing option for menu icon. https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_menu_icons

Comment: Yeah, I saw the module before, but I would actually prefer to do it without using modules.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few contrib modules that can offer this functionality.

- [Menu Item Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras)
- [Menu Manipulator](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_manipulator)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I added a custom image field to my main menu link items. I added this to my custom module.

```
function my_custom_module_entity_base_field_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'menu_link_content') {
    $fields['menu_link_image'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('image')
      ->setLabel(t('Menu link image'))
      ->setDescription(t('Upload the image related to this menu item'))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array('type' => 'string', 'weight' => 0));

    return $fields;
  }
}
```

Flush the caches and the field should appear in the Menu Item form.

The only issue I had was that I was getting a MySQL error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'menu_link_image'` when submitting the form. One solution to that was to add the column `menu_link_content` to the `menu_link_content_data` table but this is not a very good solution since you are altering a core Drupal db table.

I am still working on finding a better solution (e.g. using hook_form_alter to save that field to a different/custom db table). Any feedback/comment is appreciated.